# Reusable workflow skipping steps

Tags: designer-workflow, reusable

I have a very pressing issue. I have exported all site content types and columns and imported them in another sharepoint environment. There were some lookup columns that were used in the REUSABLE workflow (part of content types). These lookup columns have not been migrated correctly and I had to recreate them again. Now the thing is, I have added these lookup fields through the custom list settings itself and not through the parent Content Type.

I think now that my workflow skips steps because it is not able to find that column anymore. Does this make any sense? I think the field cannot be found in the workflow anymore. So a certain variable is not filled in. Will this get resolved if I recreate it in the parent content type and make it available there?